# C++ metaprogramming eager evaluation

Tags: c++, recursion, template-meta-programming

Here is my current code:

```
template<int n>
struct N{
    static const int k = (n >= 2) ? (1 + N<n-2>::k) : N<0>::k;
};

template<>
struct N<0>{
    static const int k = 0;
};
```

The following compiles:

```
int main(int, char *[])
{
    cout << N<2>::k;
    getchar();
}
```

The following does not compile:

```
int main(int, char *[])
{
    cout << N<1>::k;
    getchar();
}
```

Is the compiler eagerly computing the right branch of the ?: operator? If so, how can I make it evaluate lazily?

Comment: What is the compile error?

Comment: The error was: error C1202: recursive type or function dependency context too complex.

I was expecting the if statement to only evaluate the required branch.

Comment: Simple: add the base case N<1> because odd numbers will not hit N<0>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this example work:

```
template<int n>
struct N{
    static const int k = 1 + N<n-2>::k;
};

template<>
struct N<1>{
    static const int k = 0;
};

template<>
struct N<0>{
    static const int k = 0;
};
```

The problem lies in `N<n-2>`. When when `n=1` this will cause an infinite template instantiation depth. So this only partially will answer the question, but I don't think you can force the templates to be lazily evaluated.

Comment: On the lazy evaluation: can Boost help?

Comment: Not sure to be honest. I don't know of any boost lazy evaluation primitives.

Comment: It is possible to lazy evaluate (or it might have been my misunderstanding), but the code will be intolerably long for the function's worth.) My implementation is here: https://gist.github.com/kinchungwong/7700777

Answer (score 5):

If you're going to do this with template specialization, that's what I'd use throughout:

```
template<int n>
struct N{
    static const int k = 1 + N<n-2>::k;
};

template<>
struct N<1>{
    static const int k = 0;
};

template<>
struct N<0>{
    static const int k = 0;
};
```

Unless you're set on doing this with templates, I'd generally prefer something like:

```
int constexpr N(int n) { return n/2; }
```

Comment: :)+1 Even if left as a template, it can be simplified with the same formula!

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: good point (especially if your compiler doesn't support `constexpr`).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work and can be easily generalized to cases where you need to replace the ternary operator `?` with a lazy evaluated construct:

```
#include <iostream>

template<int n, bool = (n >= 2)>
struct N;

template<>
struct N<0, false>{
    static const int k = 0;
};

template<int n>
struct N<n, true> {
    static const int k = 1 + N<n-2>::k;
};

template<int n>
struct N<n, false> {
    static const int k = N<0>::k;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << N<2>::k << '\n'; 
    std::cout << N<1>::k << '\n';
}
```

However, with C++11 `constexpr` functions this implementation is obsolete.